# short cut to generate full properties in VS 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Please guide me what is short cut to generate full properties in Visual Studio 2008 ? Doing prop tab tab generates auto implemented properties but I am looking for short cut to generate full properties with get and set.

```
public string StringValue
    {
        get { return stringValue; }
        set { stringValue = value; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The snippet to add a full property doesn't exist in VS 2008.  `propfull` was added in 2010.

But here is a link on how to add it, by adding another .snippet file:

- [VS 2008 - I want my prop snippet back!](http://geekswithblogs.net/thibbard/archive/2008/02/08/vs-2008---i-want-my-prop-snippet-back.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The snippet you are looking for is `propfull` - see [this list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z41h7fat.aspx) of built in snippets for C# (Visual Studio 2010). It did not exist in previous versions.

Since you are using Visual Studio 2008, you can create your own code snippets.

See [Creating Code Snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165393.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: That list is for VS 2010. `propfull` does not exist for VS 2008: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z41h7fat(v=VS.90).aspx